# How to read an array (list of dictionaries) into Python Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

As a result of dealing with a gigantic dataset that takes up too much memory, I need to tap into Tensorflow's generator functions (e.g. map, apply)

I have the following array that I'd like to load into Tensorflow:

```
array = [{'field_one':'1','field_two':'2'},{'field_one':'3','field_two':'4'},{'field_one':'5','field_two':'6'}]
```

From reading the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset?hl=fr), I've tried the following:

```
import tensorflow as tf

array = [{'field_one':'1','field_two':'2'},{'field_one':'3','field_two':'4'},{'field_one':'5','field_two':'6'}]

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(array)
```

However it returns the following error:

```
ValueError: Attempt to convert a value with an unsupported type to a Tensor.
```

I've also tried the following based on [this documentation](https://www.kite.com/python/answers/how-to-convert-a-numpy-array-to-a-tensorflow-tensor-in-python) that generates the same error:

```
data_tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(array)
```

I've also tried this as well, which generates a different error:

```
tf.data.Dataset(array)
```

Error:

```
TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class DatasetV2 with abstract methods _inputs, element_spec
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't convert list of dictionnary to a Tensor. However, you can convert a single dictionnary to a tf.data.Dataset. If you merge your `array` into a single dictionnary :

```
merged_dict = dict()
for dictionary in array:
    for k,v in dictionary.items():
        if k not in merged_dict:
             merged_dict[k] = [v]
        else:
             merged_dict[k] += v
```

With `merged_dict` being now:

```
>>>> merged_dict
{'field_one': ['1', '3', '5'], 'field_two': ['2', '4', '6']}
>>> ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(merged_dict)
```

You can use it in `tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices`. Each element of the dataset will be a dictionary with two keys (`field_one` and `field_two`), and one single string as value for each key.

Comment: You should use `append() ` function when key already exist or use a list : `merged_dict[k] += [v]`

Comment: You could also use `merged_dict = defaultdict(list)`, this way you could get rid of that if statement and simply just do `merged_dict[k].append(v)`.